# Computer boots only to grub rescue mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I set up a dual boot with Windows 8 and Ubuntu. İ uninstalled Ubuntu, but my PC can't boot Windows 8. Instead I get an error message that says:

```
Error: No such partition 
grub rescue>
```

There are solutions on the web, but my problem is critical. Because in my BIOS settings, USB and DVD0ROM boots after hard disk boot selection, so I cannot boot DVD and USB drivers.

Also I cannot enter the BIOS by pressing the <kbd>F2</kbd> key (or <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc.). My computer only starts in rescue mode.

Comment: You may need to press a different key (combination) to edit BIOS settings. Besides F2 I've seen DEL, F8, F12 and Alt+F2.

Answer (score 0):

While in rescue mode, you shall need to find on which partition your GRUB file is and then restore your boot: [grub rescue, unaware of ubuntu on my machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379054/grub-rescue-unaware-of-ubuntu-on-my-machine/379060#379060).

If your computer came with Win 8 pre-installed, you likely have Secure Boot enabled in BIOS setup. It still takes an effort to make Linux work with Secure Boot, so for starters, please disable Secure Boot in BIOS setup.